# Why "Apply to all documents" option is not shown in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, compression, pictures

i noticed a strange difference between Excel and Word (tested on Office 2010 and 2013): in Word, i can disable, for example, the picture compression for all documents:
[Word screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eKfj.png)

But in Excel, the same drop-down list doesn't contains "All new documents". And this is true for all Excel options:
[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h84r5.png)

This doesn't make any sense to me. Can someone explains me why?

PS: I found a workaround in registry to disable picture compression, but i guess it is not the normal way.

Comment: "Why ... option is not shown in Excel?" - I think this was a business decision of Microsoft, don't think anybody here could give you the real answer.

Comment: Maybe you're right, i only have the Small Business edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's related to how new documents are created in the different applications.

Word is designed to format text ready for printing or presentation, so it has a lot of formatting customisation options available. To simplify storing all these options and using them over and over, every new Word document is based on a template file, `normal.dot`. When you store a setting for "All new documents", it's making that change in `normal.dot` so that new documents based on that template will pick it up.

The advantage of this method is that you can come up with a highly customised default template for all new documents that will store every option imaginable. The disadvantage is that `normal.dot` is prone to corruption, and that can cause corruption in all documents based on it.

Excel is designed to store and analyse large or complex data sets. It's not a design-oriented application, so its formatting options are much more limited. This means that it does not, by default, use a template for new workbooks. There is the capability to create such a template file, but it has to be manually created. This means that a lot of options related to formatting are only stored in individual files, and this option is one of them.

Yes, it would have been *possible* to use a `normal.xlt` template for new workbooks, but it was considered unnecessary. The relatively few options that can be set for new workbooks can be stored easily enough in a few registry keys. It's much more corruption-resistant, but harder to predict everything that someone might want to set as a default.